# How to add multiple td tags before a tr tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add multiple td tags inside a tr tag, I've tried doing that using the insert_before method

```
for table in data:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if(len(row) < 11):
            tag = soup.new_tag('td')
            for i in range(8):
                row.insert_before(tag)
```

Nothing happens after this. I've also tried

```
for table in data:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if(len(row) < 11):
            tag = soup.new_tag('td')
            for i in range(8):
                soup.row.insert_before(tag)
```

and if I do this I'm getting an error **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert_before'**

I want to add these td tags in front. I've tried the **append** method and it works fine

```
for table in data:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if(len(row) < 11):
            tag = soup.new_tag('td')
            for i in range(8):
                row.append(tag)
```

but the td tags are added at the end, not in the beginning. I want to add these empty td tags so that it will help me parse the table correctly without missing tags in between for some rows.

Edit1:
This is the result I'm getting

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The result I'm expecting is

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to add `<td>` tags inside `<tr>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
print('-' * 80)

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if len(row) < 11:
            for i in range(8):
                row.insert(-1, soup.new_tag('td'))
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely, thank you for the reply, I was able to add td tags at the end using append method as I've mentioned in the question above. I want those tags at the beginning. like this

```<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>```

can I do that using the **insert** method?

Comment: @Srikar You can use `row.insert(0, soup.new_tag('td'))` instead of `-1`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. ```row.insert(0, soup.new_tag('td'))```  using 0 instead of -1 solved the problem.